# Getting the rootelement from a streamed xml

Tags: java, xml, regex, streaming

I'm streaming an xml document using a buffer. I set the buffer quite low (50) to keep performance good. I then use the buffered string to try and extract the rootelement name from the xml (in this case i would need "abc" in the xml below):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--foobar-->
<!--<foo:bar></foo:bar>-->
<foo:abc xmlns:foo="url"><a><b>...
```

I should only get the name itself, without the alias.
Also, processing instructions and xml tags in comments should be ignored.
When there's no match, i would make the buffer larger and try to match again, until i found the rootelement.

I've created a regex that does exactly this, and returns the rootelement name. using the replace function with $4.
However when the regex DOES NOT MATCH anything, it hangs for a very long time trying to resolve the pattern...

```
(?s)(.*?(<!--.*?-->)?.*?)*<(.*?:)?([^!\?].*?)((\s+|/).*)?>.*
```

The problem seems to be in the part that tries to match the comments

```
(.*?(<!--.*?-->)?.*?)*
```

But i cant figure out how to optimize it, without breaking it...
Any ideas?

Comment: Would it be an option to use SAX parsing?

Comment: @mthmulders Can this be done while streaming? the available xmlstring will not be well-formed, as it is cut off...

Comment: SAX is only an option when the XML is well-formed. So if your XML is incomplete, don't use SAX (but in that case it isn't XML, technically).